# Can't use Parameter variable in another non-param variable

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a string array as a parameter:

```
[Parameter]
public string[] Items { get; set; }
```

And I am trying to make another variable get the first item in the array:

```
public string Placeholder = Items.First();
```

But I get this error:

```
CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Here.Items'
```

I tried making the parameter static, which made the error go in VS, but at runtime it caused another error stating that the array was empty, which it isn't because using `@Items.First()` on it's own works.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
[Parameter]
public string[] Items { get; set; }

public string Placeholder;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Placeholder = Items.First();
}
```

Comment: If I do this I get `Object of type 'Here' does not have a property matching the name 'Items'.` when I try to use the component. Using it like `<Here Items="@here" />`, Items isn't green to state that it is a parameter for the component